# Why can't I read lines from stdin, remove whitespace and push them in a vector? `line` does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I would like to read lines from stdin, remove whitespace and push them in a vector but I can't because `line` does not live long enough. Why?

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut read = Vec::new();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let line = line.trim();
        read.push(line);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:20
   |
8  |         let line = line.trim();
   |                    ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  |         read.push(line);
   |         ---- borrow later used here
10 |     }
   |     - `line` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: You need to copy the trimmed lines to new owned strings: `read.push(line.to_owned());`

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the lines, you don't need to store them in a vector first. If you just want to process them once, it's best to iterate directly over file.

Comment: Using `let line = line.trim().to_string();` also works, though I'm not sure if doing that has downsides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [`str::trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) (lifetime annotations added):

```
pub fn trim<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str
```

You can see that it returns a string slice that refers to part of the original string. That is, it borrows the string instead of copying it. Which makes sense, because the result of the `trim` is always a substring of the original one.

You may be confused by other functions, such as, [`str::to_uppercase()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_uppercase), that return a new `String`. Obviously this is because they do not return a substring of the original string, so they have to create a new one.

*TL;DR;* You have a borrowed `&str` but you want an owned `String` to store in your `Vec`. Just add `.to_string()`.

About the downsides, it will allocate a new `String`. You could try avoiding it by doing a [`trim` in place](https://crates.io/crates/trim-in-place), but I don't think it's worth it, unless you profile and you decide that your trimming is hurting your performance.